# Using output of one command as is

Tags: bash, shell

I've a command that outputs the environment variable to run particular program.

Say

```
$ outputenv --name <program name>
ENV_VARIABLE_1=<value1>;ENV_VARIABLE_2=<value2>
```

I want to use this output while running this program only for that instance.

```
$ <output of outputenv command> myprogram --options
```

Similar how I would run a program with env variables like.

```
$ ENV_VARIABLE_1=<value1>;ENV_VARIABLE_2=<value2> myprogram --options
```

Is there any way I can do it?

I tried

```
$ (outputenv --name myprogram) myprogram --options
```

and didn't help.

Comment: Looks like you have a trailing `)` in that command: `$(outputenv --name myprogram) myprogram --options)`. Remove that and it should work?

Comment: @AriSweedler, no, it still won't work, because the initial assignments are syntax; they need to be parsed in that form _before_ any expansions are run.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So the need is to have a command like `VAR1=x VAR2=y ./executable`, with env vars separated by spaces not `;`. Well in that case, `$(outputenv --name myprogram | tr ';' ' ')` to translate `;` to spaces as desired

Comment: @AriSweedler, even then, the result would need to be `eval`ed. The shell doesn't see `$(echo foo=bar)` as an assignment; instead, it tries to run a program literally named `foo=bar`.

Comment: Hmm, I am pretty sure that you can set environment variables by prefixing the command with them. Check this out in action with `MYVAR=hello env`. I am running `bash, version 3.2.57` btw

Comment: @AriSweedler, yes, you can, but it needs to be **seen that way by the parser**. Before asking me to repeat myself again, please, try `$(echo MYVAR=hello) env`, and you'll see it not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220241/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ari-sweedler).

Comment: To be clear -- `ENV_VARIABLE_1=<value1>;ENV_VARIABLE_2=<value2> myprogram --options` only exports `ENV_VARIABLE_2` in the environment of `myprogram` -- because there's a `;` after `ENV_VARIABLE_1` it's just a regular assignment, and sets up a shell variable instead of an environment variable. That's what William was talking about in [this comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529818/using-output-of-one-command-as-is/63529893#comment112340235_63529893).

Comment: ...it would need to be `ENV_VARIABLE_1=<value1> ENV_VARIABLE_2=<value2> myprogram --options`, with a space instead of a semicolon separating the two assignments, for them both to be treated as environment variables to be exported only for the duration of `myprogram`'s execution and discarded thereafter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you trust `outputenv` to generate safely shell-escaped output, then this is a job that `eval` is appropriate for:

```
( set -a; eval "$(outputenv --name myprogram)"; exec myprogram --options )
```

Starting a subshell with `(` scopes the environment changes we're making to that single process; using `set -a` makes all subsequently-assigned variables be automatically exported; using `eval` causes the content within to be parsed as syntax; using `exec` makes the subshell be replaced with a copy of `myprogram`, avoiding an unnecessary fork.

Comment: or, just `eval "$(outputenv --name myprogram) myprogram --options"`

Comment: No, that won't work. Who wrote outputenv to include semicolons?!

Comment: Anyhow, better not to `eval` the options; who knows when they'll contain potentially-hostile user-provided data?

Comment: I don't have to do `set -a` just can run the eval and it is set for the current session by just adding the end braces.

Comment: @vpshastry, if you don't do `set -a` they're just regular shell variables, not exported as environment variables. And if they're just regular shell variables, `myprogram` won't be able to see them.

Comment: (the exception to that is if there are already environment variables by the same names active; if that's true they'll be exported automatically... but do you really want to rely on that being true, when you could just run `set -a` and not need to worry about it?)

Comment: No, it does work. ```$ cat script.py
import os
print(os.environ.get('ENV_VAR_1', "NotFound"))
$ python script.py
NotFound
$ ENV_VAR_1="StackOverFlow" python script.py
StackOverFlow
```

Comment: @vpshastry, semicolons matter. Yes, `ENV_VAR_1="StackOverFlow" python script.py` works; but `ENV_VAR_1="StackOverflow"; ENV_VAR_2="Whatever" python script.py` **does not** work. And the `outputenv` sample output you showed clearly contains semicolons.

Comment: @vpshastry, ...whereas, if you make it `(set -a; ENV_VAR_1="StackOverflow"; ENV_VAR_2="Whatever" python script.py)`, you get _both_ `ENV_VAR_1` and `ENV_VAR_2` exported, instead of only getting the one(s) after the last semicolon exported.